# Método add de ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo la clase Persona

```
public class Persona {
int edad;
String nombre;
String dni;

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}
```

}

La clase ListaPersonas

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ListaPersonas {
ArrayList<Persona> l1 = new ArrayList<Persona>();
}
```

Y la clase Principal

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListaPersonas l1 = new ListaPersonas();
        l1.add(20);
        l1.add("Juan");
    }
}
```

El problema esta en que no puedo acceder el método add en la clase principal¿A que es debido este problema?Perdón por la ignorancia pero estoy empezando en programación

Comment: Creaste un método add en tu clase ListaPersonas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debes de hacer que tu clase `ListaPersonas` extienda de la clase `ArrayList` de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ListaPersonas<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    ...
}
```

Pero viendo tu código, no utilizas la clase `ListaPersonas` para nada en especial, por lo que puedes hacer directamente:

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Persona> l1 = new ArrayList<Persona>();
        Persona pers = new Persona();
        l1.add(pers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tu clase `ListaPersonas` está encapsulando un objeto de tipo `ArrayList<Persona>`, como en tu clase no has declarado ningún método para poder acceder a las funcionalidades de un `ArrayList` (por ejemplo, el método `add()`), no podrás invocar de forma directa a estos métodos, porque estás intentando llamar al método `add()` de la clase `ListaPersonas`, pero este no existe.

Una solución es declarar un método llamado `add()` en tu clase `ListaPersonas` y delegar al método `add()` de tu `ArrayList` la operación que quieres hacer:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ListaPersonas {
    ArrayList<Persona> l1 = new ArrayList<Persona>();

    public ListaPersonas() {}

    public void add(Persona persona) {
        l1.add(persona);
    }
}
```

De la misma forma, debes declarar un constructor en tu clase `Persona` para que, con el nombre, edad y dni construya un objeto de tipo `Persona`. Esto es así porque cuando agregas a la lista un objeto de este tipo, no agregas cada dato de una persona, sino un objeto **completo** a partir de todos sus datos

```
public class Persona {

    int edad;
    String nombre;
    String dni;

    public Persona(int edad, String nombre, String dni) {
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getDni() {
         return dni;
    }
}
```

E invocas este método en tu main:

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListaPersonas l1 = new ListaPersonas();
        Persona persona = new Persona(20, "Juan", "1234567890");
        l1.add(persona);
    }
}
```