# llenar lista con ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Programar una lista utilizando la clase ArrayList
La lista debe contener como mínimo 8 atributos.

Hasta el momento tengo la Clase ya creada con sus atributos, constructor vacio, contructores , getter and setter y por ultimo  toString.
Mi clase se llama Carreras.  es un java class

hasta hay todo bien pero no comprendo como hacer la lista :
esto es un java aplicacion

```
 public static void CarrerasListado() {
  ArrayList<Carreras> Lista = new ArrayList<>();
   Lista.add (Que se supone que agrege en el parentesis)
```

Comment: Es probable que esta respuesta te sirva: [**Método add de ArrayList Java**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/52008/7334)

Comment: hola @Sword, me imagino que deseas crear una lista del tipo de la clase que creaste `Carreras` y a esta agregarle los  atributos de tu clase. ?? si es así especificalo en la pregunta ,  deberías colocar el código que estas ocupando para que podamos ayudarte de manera clara, saludos.

Comment: @Ikabod Tengo que programar una lista utilizando ArrayList /   luego la lista debe contener 8 atributos / luego crear un menu / 1 rellenar datos del item /2 agregar un nuevo item /3 visualizar la informacion de todos los item /4 busqueda por criterio string / 5 busqueda por numeros /6 busqueda de ambas /eliminar codigo por codigo

Comment: sin el arraylist echo o con errores  no podre avanzar por eso la duda xd

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Método add de ArrayList Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52005/m%c3%a9todo-add-de-arraylist-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guardar lo que seteas de la clase Carreras en un ArrayList()

```
Carreras carreras = new Carreras();

ArrayList<Carreras> arrayCarreras = new ArrayList<>();

carreras.setNombreCarrera("Carrera 1");
carreras.setFechaCarrera("13-11-2018");

arrayCarreras.add(carreras);
```

De esta forma guardamos lo que esta en tu carrera dentro del array

Obtener los elementos de la carrera

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayCarreras.size() ; i++){

    System.out.println("Dato nombre carrera: "+arrayCarreras.get(i).getNombreCarrera());

 }
```

O tambien se puede recorrer la lista utilizando las nuevas utilidades de Java 8(streams). Por ejemplo:

```
arrayCarreras.forEach(c -> System.out.println("Dato nombre carrera: "+c.getNombreCarrera()));
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda sr.

Comment: Ningun problema, cualquier duda estamos para ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Programar una lista que tenga 8 atributos la verdad que no acabo de entender lo que quiere decir.

Intuyo que lo que te pide es que hagas una lista de un objeto que contenga al menos 8 atributos.

Para eso necesitas crear una clase con al menos 8 atributos, en tu caso Carrera con su constructor inicializando esos atributos y sus getters y setters como tu bien dices.

Después, cuando hayas acabado tu clase, en el main tienes que crear los objetos:
Carrera c= new Carrera(atributosDeLaClase)
Esos atributos de la clase los tienes que escribir tú, son los datos que gusrdan los atributos de la carrera. Me explico:
Si tu carrera tiene un atributo que se llama nombre por ejemplo (supongamos que la carrera tiene un nombre) deberás poner el nombre de la carrera "Indianapolis" (por ejemplo). Los valores numéricos no llevan comillas.

Después de haber creado tantos objetos como quieras y habiendo declarado tu lista ArrayListlista=new ArrayList()
Podrás hacer el ansiado lista.add(c) donde c es el nombre de la variable que guarda una de las carreras que has creado.

Comment: eso mismo muchas gracias sr.

Comment: sera usted mi profesor/a?? xd

Answer (score 1):

Debes especificar de qué es el [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ya que este es una [clase genérica](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/uso-de-java-generics/):

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(); // creando el ArrayList
lista.add(1);
lista.add(2);

ArrayList<String> lista2 = new ArrayList<>(); // creando un segundo ArrayList
lista2.add("cadena 1");
lista2.add("cadena 2");

// tambien lo puedes hacer con un objeto que hallas creado
class Student{
    private String name;
    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// en otro fichero .java
ArrayList<Student> estudiantes = new ArrayList<>();
estudiantes.add(new Student("Juan"));
estudiantes.add(new Student("Pepe"));
```

Espero que esto te sirva

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En cuanto a que debe contener 8 atributos mínimos, me imagino a que te refieras a que el `ArrayList` debe contener al menos 8 objetos. Puedes implementar tu mismo una clase que tenga un comportamiento parecido al `ArrayList` pero cuando valla a realizar una búsqueda (por ejemplo), compruebe la cantidad de elementos que contiene (método size) y si tiene menos de 8 elementos lanzar una excepción de java o una creada por ti.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hablas de 8 atributos como minimo me imagino que haces referencia a tu clase , entonces es mas facil crear un objeto de esa clase y guardar el objeto con cada uno de sus atributos en una  posicion del arrayList , entonces defines el arrayList con la clase que deseas guardar en tu caso es

```
    ArrayList<ClaseEjemplo> lista = new ArrayList<>(); // creando el Array
    ClaseEjemplo objeto1 = new ClaseEjemplo(todos los atributos de esa clase en orden 
    separados por comas); //creas el objeto de esa clase
    lista.add(objeto1);//por ultimo agregas el objeto a tu arrayList
```